# added location permission check on run time still gives error

Tags: android, google-maps, android-permissions

I have added in my activity -location permission check on run time- but I still get the error that tell me to add the permission check...
here is my code. In Oncreate () I have added:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
           bPermissionGranted = checkLocationPermission();
         }
```

In on onConnected:

```
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (bPermissionGranted) {
            Location location =     LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);

            handleNewLocation(location);

        } else {

            Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);

            handleNewLocation(location);
        }
    }
}
```

And the two method:

```
    public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;

public boolean checkLocationPermission() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        // Should we show an explanation?
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

            // Show an expanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
            // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
            // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

            //Prompt the user once explanation has been shown
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);


        } else {
            // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
        }
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                // contacts-related task you need to do.

                Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
                LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);

                handleNewLocation(location);


            } else {

                // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                // functionality that depends on this permission.
                Toast.makeText(this, "permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return;
        }

        // other 'case' lines to check for other
        // permissions this app might request
    }
}
```

And it still mark the follow with red error:

```
Location location =  LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well your code is somewhat fine. Don't check for permission in `onCreate`. Check it in your `onConnected()` method because its possible that the user has not granted the permission yet and `onConnected()` is executed before.

Then when you receive the permission result in `onRequestPermissionsResult()`, then start fetching the location updates if the result is positive.

Also an advice -

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
```

This piece of code is redundant. Android only requires run time permissions in Android M and above so your permission check code would only be executed if the Android version is above M else it won't execute.

Comment: in onCreate  : bPermissionGranted = checkLocationPermission() - actually takes me to the dialog with the user(onRequestPermissionsResult)...i m initializing bPermissionGranted with the user response..

Comment: I know buddy you're initialising bPermissionGranted with the user response but your `onConnected()` can be called before the user provides response. Then you'll have a problem as bPermissionGranted would not be initialised at that moment. That is why start your code in `onConnected()`.